# have we limitation in submit some query in c# to oracle

Tags: c#, sql, oracle

Can I send this query from my C# connection to my oracle connection?

```
"Select Object_name,status from object_name where object_type='function';"
```

or

```
"Select Object_name,status from object_name where object_type='Procedure';"
```

or

because as I remember, I have this problem when I write a program to connect to Access with java,those days I try to submit some query to get all table name.

regard.

Comment: Not sure, but I think you mean to query `USER_OBJECTS` (or `ALL_OBJECTS` or `DBA_OBJECTS`). If so, the `object_type` will be uppercase, e.g. `'FUNCTION'`, `'PROCEDURE'`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the Command object:

```
OracleCommand objCmd = new OracleCommand();
objCmd.Connection = objConn;
objCmd.CommandText = "count_emp_by_dept";
objCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
objCmd.Parameters.Add("pin_deptno", OracleType.Number).Value = 20;
objCmd.Parameters.Add("pout_count", OracleType.Number).Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;
```

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/john_charles/CallingOraclestoredproceduresfromMicrosoftdotNET06222007142805PM/CallingOraclestoredproceduresfromMicrosoftdotNET.aspx

Comment: I wanna develop an IDE for Sql,like  Oracle Sql Developer,so I cant add a procedure or do any changes!
any better idea?

Comment: I wanna know how some program like Oracle Sql Developer do their job?
where i can find good knowledge?